Deriving the Unit Quaternion to Tait-Bryan Angles conversion.
Let me start by saying I have a working solution. But I just don't understand how to get there. I've followed the well-written paper Technical Concepts
Orientation, Rotation, Velocity and Acceleration, and the SRM and a few other sources. Specifically sections 3.4.9 and 3.4.10.
If I start with making a quaternion for Tait-Bryan angles $a_x, a_y, a_z$ I get the unit quaternion.
$$
q_x = cos(\frac{a_z}{2}) cos(\frac{a_y}{2}) sin(\frac{a_x}{2}) - sin(\frac{a_z}{2}) sin(\frac{a_y}{2}) cos(\frac{a_x}{2}) \\
q_y = cos(\frac{a_z}{2}) sin(\frac{a_y}{2}) cos(\frac{a_x}{2}) + sin(\frac{a_z}{2}) cos(\frac{a_y}{2}) sin(\frac{a_x}{2}) \\
q_z = sin(\frac{a_z}{2}) cos(\frac{a_y}{2}) cos(\frac{a_x}{2}) - cos(\frac{a_z}{2}) sin(\frac{a_y}{2}) sin(\frac{a_x}{2}) \\
q_w = cos(\frac{a_z}{2}) cos(\frac{a_y}{2}) cos(\frac{a_x}{2}) + sin(\frac{a_z}{2}) sin(\frac{a_y}{2}) sin(\frac{a_x}{2})
$$
When trying to convert back to angles I know that in the end we get
$$
sin(a_y) = -2 (q_x q_z - q_w q_y) \\
sin(a_y) = 2 * sin(\frac{a_y}{2}) * cos(\frac{a_y}{2}) \\
s = sin(2 * \frac{a_y}{2}) \\
s = sin(a_y) \\
a_y = arcsin(s)
$$
Using the double angle trig identity. However there is a big jump there between the first and second steps and I don't understand how to transform from the first to the second.
Here's my attempt. Apologies I'm going to drop to pseudo-code here because my latex skills are lacking. If we make some shorthand and expand we get to:
s = 2 (q.w * q.y - q.x * q.z)

var x, y, z = cos(a.x/2), cos(a.y/2), cos(a.z/2)
var a, b, c = sin(a.x/2), sin(a.y/2), sin(a.z/2)

q.w * q.y -> (xyz + abc) * (xbz + ayc)
expand    -> xyzxbz + xyzayc + abcxbz + abcayc

q.x * q.z -> (ayz - xbc) * (xyc - abz)
expand    -> ayzxyc - xbcxyc - ayzabz + xbcabz

(wy - xz)  -> xyzxbz + xyzayc + abcxbz + abcayc - (ayzxyc - xbcxyc - ayzabz + xbcabz)
distribute -> xyzxbz + xyzayc + abcxbz + abcayc - ayzxyc + xbcxyc + ayzabz - xbcabz
rearrange  -> xxybzz + xayyzc + xabbzc + aaybcc - xayyzc + xxybcc + aaybzz - xabbzc
cancel     -> xxybzz + aaybcc + xxybcc + aaybzz

So now we have
$$
s = 2 * xxybzz + aaybcc + xxybcc + aaybzz \\
xxybzz = cos(\frac{x}{2})^2 * cos(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{y}{2}) * cos(\frac{z}{2})^2 \\
aaybcc = sin(\frac{x}{2})^2 * cos(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{z}{2})^2 \\
xxybcc = cos(\frac{x}{2})^2 * cos(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{z}{2})^2 \\
aaybzz = sin(\frac{x}{2})^2 * cos(\frac{y}{2}) * sin(\frac{y}{2}) * cos(\frac{z}{2})^2 \\
$$
And this is where I'm stuck unsure of how to reduce further.
EDIT
I think I figured it out, going back to the shorthand pseudocode:
...
cancel     -> xxybzz + aaybcc + xxybcc + aaybzz
factor.    -> (yb)*(xxzz+aacc+xxcc+aazz)
rearrange  -> (yb)*(xxzz+xxcc+aazz+aacc)
factor     -> (yb)*(xx+aa)(zz+cc)

Now we have
$$
s = 2 (cos(\frac{y}{2}) sin(\frac{y}{2})) (cos(\frac{x}{2})^2 + sin(\frac{x}{2})^2) (cos(\frac{z}{2})^2 + sin(\frac{z}{2})^2) \\
$$
And by applying the pythagorean trig identity we can reduce to:
$$
s = 2 (cos(\frac{y}{2}) sin(\frac{y}{2})) (1) (1) \\
s = 2 cos(\frac{y}{2}) sin(\frac{y}{2}) \\
$$
And then finally we're back to the double angle identity
$$
s = sin(2 * \frac{y}{2}) \\
s = sin(y)
$$
MORE EDIT
For posterity, and since it took my 3 days to figure out, here's the reconstruction for all rotation orders in pseudocode (not accounting for singularities).
// extrinsic XYZ
ax = atan2(qx*qw + qy*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qy^2 )
ay = asin(2 * (qy*qw - qx*qz))
az = atan2(qz*qw + qx*qy, (1/2) - qy^2 - qz^2)

// extrinsic XZY
ax = atan2(qx*qw - qy*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qz^2)
ay = atan2(qy*qw - qx*qz, (1/2) - qy^2 - qz^2)
az = asin(2 * (qx*qy + qz*qw))

// extrinsic YXZ
ax = asin(2 * (qy*qz + qx*qw))
ay = atan2(qy*qw - qx*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qy^2)
az = atan2(qz*qw - qx*qy, (1/2) - qx^2 - qz^2)

// extrinsic YZX
ax = atan2(qx*qw + qy*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qz^2)
ay = atan2(qy*qw + qx*qz, (1/2) - qy^2 - qz^2)
az = asin(2 * (qz*qw - qx*qy))

// extrinsic ZXY 
ax = asin(2 * (qx*qw - qy*qz))
ay = atan2(qy*qw + qx*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qy^2)
az = atan2(qz*qw + qx*qy, (1/2) - qx^2 - qz^2)

// extrinsic ZYX
ax = atan2(qx*qw - qy*qz, (1/2) - qx^2 - qy^2)
ay = asin(2 * (qz*qx + qy*qw))
az = atan2(qz*qw - qx*qy, (1/2) - qy^2 - qz^2)


For your situation use the following code to define some quantities
dy = cy^2+sy^2
ey = cy^2-sy^2
dx = cx^2+sx^2
dz = cz^2+sz^2
qx = cz*cy*sx - sz*sy*cx
qy = cz*sy*cx + sz*cy*sx
qz = sz*cy*cx - cz*sy*sx
qw = cz*cy*cx + sz*sy*sx

Verify that the four expressions
F1 = qx^2 + qy^2 + qz^2 + qw^2 - dx*dy*dz
F2 = qw*qy - qx*qz - dx*dz*sy*cy
F3 = qw*qx + qy*qz - ey*dz*sx*cx
F4 = qw*qz + qx*qy - dx*ey*sz*cz

all expand to zero.
Substitute $\,\sin(\frac{a_x}2),\cos(\frac{a_x}2)\,$ for sx,cx and
similarly for $\,y\,$ and $\,z.$
Note that ey is $\,\cos(a_y)\,$ and dx = dy = dz = 1 using standard
trig identities.
$\,F_1 = 0\,$ implies that $\,(q_x,q_y,q_z,q_w)\,$ is a unit quaternion.
$\,F_2 = 0\,$ implies that $\,q_wq_y - q_xq_z = \sin(a_y)/2\,$ using
a double angle identity.
$\,F_3 = 0\,$  implies that $\,q_wq_x + q_yq_z = \cos(a_y)\sin(a_x)/2.\,$
$\,F_4 = 0\,$  implies that $\,q_wq_z + q_xq_y = \cos(a_y)\sin(a_z)/2.$
Use these to solve for $\,a_y\,$ and then $\,a_x,a_z\,$ using inverse
trig functions.

Thanks for the answer! I've been staring at this since last night.
F1 is straight forward, but how do you choose the terms for F2-4?
I need to understand it so I can extend to other rotation order conventions.

@MichaelMarcin There are only a few reasonable choices. I factored them all using Mathematica to find out which ones factored nicely.

Thanks I also spent the day learning the wolfram language to try and figure it out. This confirms I'm on an okay path. Appreciate it!
